# how java uses recursion to reverse a string

Tags: java, recursion

Here is a recursive method:

```
public static String reverseRecursively(String str) {

    //base case to handle one char string and empty string
    if (str.length() < 2) {
        return str;
    }
    System.out.println(str.substring(1) + " "+  str.charAt(0));
    return reverseRecursively(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
}
```

Obviously it is supposed to reverse a `String`. The output I get from this method is this:

```
23456 1
3456 2
456 3
56 4
6 5
654321
```

It works fine. But the problem is, I don't understand *how* it works. After looking at the output, I am totally confused. All I understand, is that it returns a truncated `String` that gets shorter and shorter. Can someone please provide an explanation how this exactly works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Detailed explanation:

First you start with this String:

```
"123456"
```

And it first reaches this condition:

```
if (str.length() < 2) {
    return str;
}
```

The `String` is longer than 1 character so it does nothing here. The next executed method is this:

```
System.out.println(str.substring(1) + " "+  str.charAt(0));
```

For simplicity we are just looking at the inner part:

```
str.substring(1) + " " +  str.charAt(0)
```

So here are two method `substring(int)` and `charAt(int)`.

1. `substring(int)`: This method returns as the name implies a substring of the original string. It starts at the index you pass into the method.
2. `charAt(int)`: This returns the character at the given position in the `String`.

So now if we again look at the code in the method, remember currently str is "123456".

If we use `substring(1)` on this `String` it will return everything beginning at index 1, so `substring(1)` returns "23456". Just the first character is left out.

If we use `charAt(0)` we get the first character in the `String`m so `charAt(0)` returns just "1".

So now we know what values are returned by those methods in the first iteration:

```
str.substring(1) + " " +  str.charAt(0) = "23456 1"
     |                        |
     V                        V
  "23456"        + " " +     "1"        = "23456 1"
```

And after that the recursion starts:

```
return reverseRecursively(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
```

So the value of `str.substring(1)` is now passed into `reverseRecursively()`. The `str.charAt(0)` here is just appended to the `String` once `reverseRecursively()` returns. In other words it looks like this:

```
return reverseRecursively("23456") + "1";
```

In the next iteration everything starts over, the only difference is that now `reverseRecursively()` starts with the `String` "23456" instead of "123456". So in the end it would come down to this:

```
return reverseRecursively("3456") + "2" + "1";
```

Again in the next iteration it would work out to this:

```
return reverseRecursively("456") + "3" + "2" + "1";
```

And this goes on and on until the `String` passed into `reverseRecursively()` has a length smaller than two, so once the recursion reaches this:

```
reverseRecursively("6")
```

The if statement will kick in and just return the `String` `"6"`.

```
if (str.length() < 2) {
    return str;
}
```

So in the end the result will be this:

```
"6" + "5" + "4" + "3" + "2" + "1" = "654321"
```

---

### Summary

> **So to summarise:**
>
> What this method does is take everything from the `String` but the
>   first character and the first character is added to the end of the
>   `String` after passing the rest of the `String` again into
>   `reverseRecursively()` again causing the first character to be
>   appended to the end and everything else starts over. The whole thing
>   stops once the `String` reaches a length of 1.

So what this all boils down to is this:

```
                         "123456"  
                    "23456" + "1"  
               "3456" + "2" + "1"  
          "456" + "3" + "2" + "1"  
     "56" + "4" + "3" + "2" + "1"  
"6" + "5" + "4" + "3" + "2" + "1" = "654321"
```

I hope I could explain the algorithm properly! If you have any further questions please feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1):

It works the same way any recursive function works. It calls itself recursively until it hits the terminating condition: `str.length() < 2` in this case. Then that final/deepest function call returns, and then the calling function call also returns, and its calling function call also returns and so on. And you get the result back.

Comment: but how is it reversing the string ?

Comment: It's reversing it correctly because you 1) reverse the tail 2) you append str.charAt(0) /the first char/ as a last char to the reversed tail (see the last line of your method body). By "tail" I mean the string without its first char. Try it by hand and you'll see why it works.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to reverse a string using recursion, this particular example generates the reversed string as the stack unfolds.

The following illustration may help, you printed out the arguments as the calls happened (got pushed onto the stack).   Here is what happens as it unwinds.  On each line I have replaced the call to rev with its recursive call, which is another call to rev and a concatenation.  Until the string has less than two characters at which point it stops.

```
rev("1234")
rev("234") + "1"
(rev("34") + "2") + "1"
((rec("4") + "3") + "2") + "1"
(("4" + "3") + "2") + "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that prints a string in reverse.

```
public static void reverseRecursively(String str) {
    //Base case
    if (str.length() < 2) {
        System.out.println(str);
        return;
    }
    //Recursive Call the string without the first charecter
    reverseRecursively(str.substring(1));

    //print the first char of the string
    System.out.println(str.charat(0));
}
```

Okay,  whats happening here is when you call the function the parameter 'str' is passed.  For this example lets say the value of str is "Waffle".  The base case is not met because our string is too long.  The next line of code is the recursive call.  "affle" is passed to the new function. Since we are already inside a function all of the memory from it is pushed onto the "Stack Frame".  This snapshots the value of 'str' and puts it aside for later.  Visual representation:

"Waffle" -> passed into recursiveFunction
     No basecase met
     New recursiveFunction is called
     Stack Frame is saved for when the New function returns
     "affle"-> passed into recursiveFunction
          No basecase met
          New recursiveFunction is called
          Another stack frame is pushed saving "affle"
                  "ffle" is passed to new recursive function

this process is repeated untill the basecase is met.  Once the return is called (the value of 'str' will = "e", my function prints "e" before the return) ,  the stackFrame Pops and the value of 'str' is returned to the previous value of "le".  The next line is the print statment which prints the first charecter of str so "l" gets printed.

This is repeated untill all frames have finished running.

Resulting in the consol looking like this:
e
l
f
f
a
w